# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a calculator function. While trying that I am getting the Syntax Error. Please help me to sort out this error.

```
#Addition
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

#subtraction
def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

#Multiplication
def mul(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

#Division
def div(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2


def main():
    operation = input("What do you want to do  +,-.*,/: ")
    if(operation != '+' and operation != '-' and operation != '*' and operation != '/'):
    #invalid operation
        print("please enter valid operation")
    else:
        var1 = int(input("Enter num1: "))
        var2 = int(input("Enter num2: "))
    if(operation == '+'):
        print(add(var1, var2))
    elif(operation == '-'):
        print(sub(var1, var2))
    elif(operation == '*'):
        print(mul(var1, var2))
    else:
        print(div(var1, var2))

main()
```

When I run my code:
And I enter +,-,*,/

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\Calculator1.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\python\Calculator1.py", line 19, in main
    operation = input("What do you want to do  +,-.*,/: ")
  File "<string>", line 1
    -
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `input()` function, which interprets the input as *Python code*. `-` is not a valid Python expression and you get a syntax error.

Use the `raw_input()` function instead; it just takes the user input and returns that as a string. Your code is already handling conversion to integers for the numbers.

Demo:

```
>>> input('')
-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    -
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
>>> raw_input('')
-
'-'
```

You may have a book or tutorial for Python that assumes you are using Python 3 instead here. In Python 3 `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()` and the Python 2 implementation for `input()` was dropped altogether.